# Google Protocol Buffers. C++ error: 'protobuf' does not name a type

Tags: c++, protocols, buffer, protocol-buffers

I have the following code which I'm really struggling to compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "test.pb.h"

using namespace google::protobuf;
using namespace std;


protobuf::RpcChannel* channel;   //error on this line!
```

I keep getting this `'protobuf' does not name a type` error. I have no idea how to fix this ;(

Any insight greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: What header is it supposed to be declared in? Have you included that?

Comment: I don't really know... Do you know how I can find out?

Comment: @Bo Persson, it's not a continuation question. That issue was solved.

Comment: I understand that the programmer must implement RpcChannel (http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/proto.html#services) "The stub forwards all calls to an RpcChannel, which in turn is an abstract interface that you must define yourself in terms of your own RPC system. For example, you might implement an RpcChannel which serializes the message and sends it to a server via HTTP. In other words, the generated stub provides a type-safe interface for making protocol-buffer-based RPC calls, without locking you into any particular RPC implementation. ", but I have no idea how to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `protobuf` namespace, since you did `using namespace google::protobuf` (which you shouldn't). Do `namespace protobuf = google::protobuf` instead.

Comment: Hey, I tried `namespace protobuf=google::protobuf` and I got this error now: "‘RpcChannel’ in namespace ‘protobuf’ does not name a type"

Comment: @Eamorr: Then you're missing a header, look into docs to see what needs to be included.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include #include "google\protobuf\service.h"  in the file you are using RpcChannel not in the headers.